# Specify a specific double precision literal in c#

Tags: c#, double

How can I specify a specific `double` precision literal or value in c#?

For example, I would like to use the constant of the largest `double` value less than one in a program. The largest `double` less than one is `1.11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 1111 x 2^(-1)` in binary. Expressing this as a big-endian double in hex would be `0x3fe f ffff ffff ffff`

I can generate it with the following code:

```
var largestDoubleLessThanOneBytes = new byte[] {0x3f, 0xef, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) largestDoubleLessThanOneBytes = largestDoubleLessThanOneBytes.Reverse().ToArray();
double largestDoubleLessThanOne = BitConverter.ToDouble(largestDoubleLessThanOneBytes, 0);
```

`BitConverter` can't be used in the declaration of a `const`, so this can't be used in place of a literal value.

Using [this tool](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF), I can come up with the literal `9.99999999999999888977697537484E-1`, which ends up being exactly the same double. `BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(9.99999999999999888977697537484E-1)) == "FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-EF-3F"`.

Is there any other way to get specific `double` values into c# code than to find a decimal literal whose closest double representation is the double you want?

Comment: You can also get c# code to spit out an appropriate decimal literal for a double with `.ToString("R")`. In this case it would be `0.99999999999999989`. Attempting to add enough decimal places to a string format to output a value precise enough to use as a literal doesn't work, for why see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp

Comment: In Java, I would use Math.nextAfter(1.0, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY). Is this perhaps a case for a C# nextAfter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably overkill, but damn, why not?

```
unsafe
{
    var x = 0x3fefffffffffffff;
    var d = *(double*)&x;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:r}", d);
}
```

hello, `reinterpret_cast<>` in C#

Comment: Unfortunately, the .Net 4.5 C# compiler isn't clever enough to optimize away `*&`, much less `*(double*)&`. It results in a `ldc.i8`, `stloc`, `lsloca.s`, `conf.u`, `ldind.r8`, `stloc` and uses two locals instead of simply `ldc.r8`, `stloc` using a single local.

Comment: The real optimizations in .Net code are made during the JIT compilation. I don't know how smart the JITter is, but it may play a significant role here. Anyway, since you want to specify a compile-time constant it shouldn't matter much.